# The title of a manga where aliens have existed on earth after arriving for partners

Tags: story-identification, manga

The main characters include the protagonist, who is against humans mixing with aliens, an alien girl who catches on fire, an egotistical girl with cat ears, and a friend of the guy that's both evil and perverted

Comment: Hi and welcome to Scifi stackexchange! When you're able, can you add more details (where/when you read this, anything else) by [edit]ing them in? And when you're done, would you mind reading the [tour], it should help explain more about this website?

Answer (score -1):

Otome no Harawata Hoshi no Iro

Comment: Could you explain why you think this is the manga that the questioner is looking for?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Scifi stackexchange! When you're able, can you add more details as to why you think this is the correct answer by [edit]ing them in? And when you're done, would you mind reading the [tour], it should help explain more about this website?